# ImportError: No module named usb.core (Working in terminal, not in Eclipse)

Tags: python, pyusb

I'm trying to get the pyUSB to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 distribution, more specifically in Eclipse. I've installed the package several times using different methods, and the last one combined with some magic did the trick! It is working in the Terminal (see image)

[image]

But I cannot import the `usb.core` lib in Eclipse. I still get that error `ImportError: No module named usb.core`

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import usb.core

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x05fe,idProduct=0x1010)
if dev is None:    
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
else:
    print('Device found')
```

Can anyone please help me getting this to work in Eclipse? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what interpreter is eclipse using?

Comment: At the terminal you're loading python 2.7.6 and in Eclipse it's 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PyDev Package Explorer`, it looks to me like your project is associated with `/usr/local/bin/python3.2`. However, when you run `python` from the command line, you're running version 2.7.6. Find out where your `python` binary lives by running `which python` on the command line (it'll probably return `/usr/bin/python`), then configure Eclipse to use that version for your projects.